# Nextcloud installation broken after upgrading to Ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-20.04, nextcloud

I'm currently running Nextcloud on Ubuntu server. After upgrading from 20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS, I couldn't log into Nextcloud. I switched the PHP modules from 7.4 to 8.1 as recommended in [this forum post](https://help.nextcloud.com/t/broken-nextcloud-after-ubuntu-lts-upgrade-to-php8-1/138355), but I still can't log in. Whenever I go to the login page, I just get this error:

> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator if this error reappears multiple times, please include the technical details below in your report.
> More details can be found in the server log.

The server log isn't giving me any useful information. I confirmed that https is working fine, as I can access the Apache server's homepage in my browser. I'm using MariaDB as the database for Nextcloud and I did the manual installation, not the snap installation. My Nextcloud version is 24.0.6.1. Any ideas on how to get my server running again?

Comment: Read the server log. Increase log verbosity if necessary. Nextcloud also has its own log file in the data directory. Most probably it's just a missing PHP module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was. I switched back to php7.4 since according to my research, Nextcloud compatibility with php8.1 is still unpredictable. It turns out apt upgraded several PHP modules to the 8.1 versions when I upgraded to Ubuntu server 22.04 LTS. I used `php -m` to check the modules installed and it was missing curl, mbstring, zip and several others. I reinstalled them and Nextcloud is working fine now.